# Populate new column in DF1 if List in DF2 is in List in DF1. Can be multiple updates in DF1, so need the results to be in a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

```
DF1:

NAME   LIST_1
BILL   ['ZF1', 'ZF2', 'ZF3', 'ZF9', 'ZF11']
PAUL   ['ZF1', 'ZF4', 'ZF5', 'ZF2', 'ZF3']
JOHN   ['ZF1', 'ZF2', 'ZF5', 'ZF6']

DF2:

ID     LIST_2
ZB1    ['ZF1', 'ZF2', 'ZF3']
ZB2    ['ZF1', 'ZF4', 'ZF5']
ZB3    ['ZF2', 'ZF5', 'ZF6']

NEEDED RESULT:

DF1 (Can also be a new DF):

NAME   LIST_1                                 MATCH 
BILL   ['ZF1', 'ZF2', 'ZF3', 'ZF9', 'ZF11']   ['ZB1']
PAUL   ['ZF1', 'ZF4', 'ZF5', 'ZF2', 'ZF3']    ['ZB1', 'ZB2']
JOHN   ['ZF1', 'ZF2', 'ZF5', 'ZF6']           ['ZB3']
```

I have not really tried much of anything yet as I am confused by the list comparisons. I expect I will need to explode DF1 and DF2 and compare and use merge? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```py
df1['MATCH'] = df1.apply(lambda x: [i for i, l in zip(df2.ID, df2.LIST_2) if all(v in x['LIST_1'] for v in l)] , axis=1)

print(df1)
```

Prints:

```
   NAME                      LIST_1       MATCH
0  BILL  [ZF1, ZF2, ZF3, ZF9, ZF11]       [ZB1]
1  PAUL   [ZF1, ZF4, ZF5, ZF2, ZF3]  [ZB1, ZB2]
2  JOHN        [ZF1, ZF2, ZF5, ZF6]       [ZB3]
```

---

*Optionally*: If values in `LIST_1`/`LIST_2` columns are strings, convert them to lists:

```py
from ast import literal_eval

df1.LIST_1 = df1.LIST_1.apply(literal_eval)
df2.LIST_2 = df2.LIST_2.apply(literal_eval)
```

Comment: This seems to have worked. Breaking this down (to make sure I understand): For each row in All_Functions (X), if each list element (v) is in FUNCTIONS (l) then it zips the result to MATCH? I am unclear how zip is working in this case 'zip(df2.ID, df2.LIST_2)' as I would have expected the result in MATCH to include ID and LIST_2?

Comment: @PaulDemay `zip(df2.ID, df2.LIST_2)` is returning 2-value tuples from `df2` (`(ZB1, ['ZF1', 'ZF2', 'ZF3']`, `(ZB2, ['ZF1', 'ZF4', 'ZF5'])`, `(ZB3, ['ZF2', 'ZF5', 'ZF6']`). I then check if all values from the list from `df2` are present in the list from `df1`

Answer (score 0):

It's always tricky to work with Series of lists in pandas.

The most reasonable approach is likely to use set operations:

```
lst = list(zip(df2['LIST_2'].apply(frozenset), df2['ID']))

df1['MATCH'] = [[ID for s, ID in lst if s.issubset(l)]
                for l in df1['LIST_1']]
```

Output:

```
   NAME                      LIST_1       MATCH
0  BILL  [ZF1, ZF2, ZF3, ZF9, ZF11]       [ZB1]
1  PAUL   [ZF1, ZF4, ZF5, ZF2, ZF3]  [ZB1, ZB2]
2  JOHN        [ZF1, ZF2, ZF5, ZF6]       [ZB3]
```